# Name for Magento 'pseudo' constructor

Tags: class

I understand why and how Magento uses the secondary/pseudo constructor e.g. the constructor that begins with a single underscore.

Is there a specific name for this method:

pseudo constructor
secondary constructor
etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen anything official on this over the years — I vacillate between calling it Magento's pseudo-constructor or Magento's internal-constructor.  Looking at the method definition

```
#File: lib/Varien/Object.php
/**
 * Internal constructor not depended on params. Can be used for object initialization
 */
protected function _construct()
{
}
```

it looks like *Internal constructor* is the closest thing we have to a proper name.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically is it a method. With this interpretation the name is badly chosen :-)

I don't think there is something like a "pseudo constructor", "second constructor", etc.

A constructor is a method which is called **AUTOMATICALLY**, and there is onle one which is called automatically in php: `__construct`.

And to be honest: I don't understand why and how magento uses this concept, please explain :-)

Comment: The why is to have a place for constructor like behavior **without** needing to worry about parameters into the constructor.  This way people writing classes that inherit from `Varien_Object` can have a constructor for initialization without worrying about what parameters the parent class used (as they'd have to if they redefined the real constructor)

Answer (score 0):

There is a stackoverflow question already out there with some more details on both Alan and Fabians answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706352/why-does-magento-have-construct-and-construct-methods